# How to initiate NSArray with objects passed by method with variable argument list

Tags: objective-c

Is it possible to do that this way:

```
- (void) setList:(id) firstObj,...
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args,firstObj);
    list = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:args]; // Compile error
    va_end(args);
}
```

Comment: Yepp. `...` is **not** a `va_list`. Even Dropbox's "developers" made the very same error which I emailed them about...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (void) setList:(id)firstObj, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, firstObj);
    list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:firstObj, nil];
    id obj;
    while ((obj = va_arg(args, id)) != nil) {
        [list addObject:obj];
    }
    va_end(args);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will do it that way.

Comment: The first object is not part of the `va_list` and you should add a [`sentinel`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) attribute so the compiler knows it should be `nil` terminated, see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12319425/418715).

Comment: I'm not sure if you can send `initWithObject:` on NSMutableArray. Guess you'll have to do it like this: `list = [[NSMutableArray] initWithObjects:firstObj, nil];`

Comment: @kervich Right, I was confusing it with `arrayWithObject:`. It's incomprehensible why there's no designated initializer matching the convenience method...

Comment: For that I carry a repository of categories providing convenience methods from project to project )

Answer (score 5):

`NSArray` does not have a constructor that takes a `va_list` so you will have to loop over the args yourself and add them to a mutable array. You should also add a constraint for the arguments to be `nil` terminated.

```
- (void) setList:(id) firstObj,... __attribute__((sentinel)) //make sure it is nil terminated
{
    //You have to add the first object yourself
    NSMutableArray *tmplist = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:firstObj];
    va_list args;
    va_start(args,firstObj);

    id arg; 
    while((arg = va_arg(args, id)) != nil)
        [tmplist addObject:arg];

    va_end(args);

    list = [tmplist copy];
}
```

Comment: just a minor point: `__attribute__((sentinel))` is already defined as `NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION` - maybe it's a bit portable to use it like this. +1 for your answer, though.

Comment: Yes that is correct, that is how Apple decorates their variable args but I could not find it in the documentation besides [Cocoa with Love](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/05/variable-argument-lists-in-cocoa.html) so I just added the `gcc` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty close, something like this should work. The problem is that there isn't an API function for this, so you have to get the objects out of the list and add them to an array your instantiate.

```
-(void *)setList:(id)firstObj, ... {
    //The array you're holding everything in
    arr = [NSMutableArray array];
    [arr addObject:firstObject];

    //Get the variable list
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, action1);

    //Create the object
    id object = va_arg(args, id);

    //Keep adding objects until you run out
    while(object) {
        [arr addObject:object];
        object = va_arg(args, id);
    }

    va_end(args);
}
```